# The "loading when this answer was accepted" tooltip won't go away by itself

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, tooltips

Something I noticed a while ago and finally decided to pick up the glove and report here.

For some time now (guess since the live updates rolled out) the time in which answer was accepted is not loaded with the rest of the contents but instead loaded "on demand" when the user hover over the checkmark. So far so good and the concept itself is working.

However, when initially hovering the tooltip says "loading when this answer was accepted..." and stay like this for good. Only when going away from the ticked checkmark and hovering again, the tooltip is updated.

I understand this is [JavaScript limitation](http://jsfiddle.net/D8Le6/) that won't reflect the changed tooltip so there's no simple solution, except maybe switching to custom tooltip plugin.