# "Loading when the answer was accepted" tooltip prevails when closing as duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, accepted-answer, tooltips

When flagging a question as duplicate you notice `"Loading when the answer was accepted"` tool-tip..

> [image]

It definitely looked like a bug, but then I came across [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166144/221351). Which meant that there used to be such kind of tool-tip. Although it was for main question, mine is when flagging as duplicate.<sub>Worth noticing the above mentioned tooltip is no longer issue in question pages.(bug fixes in new rollout I guess.)</sub>

So, I suggest make them consistent by providing the same tooltip as `answer accepted as best answer by user**** at .....` ... If thats really a pain to implement then `this is an accepted answer` or `this answer was accepted`(i.e without the time and OP name) tooltip will do as well..

Comment: Doesn't look like there's any AJAX request at all in that case, so the default placeholder never gets replaced.